# WP Query по категориям

Tags: php, wordpress

Мне нужно сделать запрос в базу следующего вида:
Вытянуть все посты которые присоединены к категориям например category_1, category_2, category_3. В свою очередь каждая из категорий имеет одну общую категорию main_category. В результате мне нужно получить сумму всех постов

```
main_category + category_1
main_category + category_2
main_category + category_3
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'status'    => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => [ 'main_category', 'category_1' ],
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => [ 'main_category', 'category_2' ],
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => [ 'main_category', 'category_3' ],
        ],
    ],
];

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```